# Is it possible for an offchain worker to submit calls to an extrinsic with ensure_root?

Tags: substrate

Is it possible to decorate an extrinsic, so that only an offchain worker can execute it?

Answer (score 2):

Your title and description are two different questions in my opinion. Notably, one is a more general form of the other one.

> Is it possible for an offchain worker to submit calls to an extrinsic with ensure_root?

As mentioned in the previous comment, no, but you could hypothetically do it if you have a sudo module in your runtime. The sudo module essentially allows a particular key to act as the root. Your offchain worker would need a way to know the sudo key's private key though, and providing that is not something that we have any recipes for, but it is possible.

> Is it possible to decorate an extrinsic, so that only an offchain worker can execute it?

Not directly, but again, you can mock it. Note that your offchain worker is really the same as a binary that is running outside of the chain, so it can for example read keys from a secret key store on the local machine. So again, a feasible workaround is to protect your transaction so that it only accepts transactions from specific key(s). Then give that private key for signing to the offchain worker.

This is similar and the general form of what I said above about the sudo key.

---

But all in all, if you were hoping for a `ensure_offchain(origin)`, no this is not possible. All that I said above is also hypothetical and as I said, somewhat eccentric things to do. So consider re-evaluating *why* your need this feature before trying to do any of them.

Comment: I'm trying to create something that registers all the nodes and rewards them.
How do we get all the current connected nodes in a blockchain in a runtime?
Maby you could use an offchain worker that fetches the current nodes peerid with 
```http::Request::post("http://127.0.0.1:9933/", core::str::from_utf8(&test).unwrap()``` and saves them connected to one ```T::AccountId```
ofcourse there must be only one ```T::AccountId``` able to do that

Comment: Yeah you could use an offchain worker, but typically a runtime cannot know about this stuff. You need to inform it via an extrinsic, which is basically what the offchain worker is also doing.

Answer (score 1):

No. Root calls can only come from within the runtime. Remember that an offchain worker is not "special" to the runtime. In fact the runtime has no knowledge of the existence of the offchain worker at all.

You should think about the offchain worker as some external program that comes packaged with the runtime. But this code does not need to come to consensus, so calls coming from the offchain worker should be considered just like any external call (since it is).

If someone wanted to, they could write their own software that would pretend to be some offchain worker, and the runtime would not know different.